# Is it possible to explicitly retrieve full file contents with bad checksum on a btrfs filesystem?

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs, checksum

Imagine a situation when a file became corrupted on a single device Btrfs. And in this case file contents are needed as is including corrupted bits.

As stated in man page for mount:

```
nodatasum
              Enable/disable data checksumming for newly created files.
```

So it won't disable checksum checks when reading files.

And as I guess all standard system calls involving filesystem for reading will fail at this file. Raw disk read is not an option because of likely fragmentation.

When I try to `cat` such file, I get error:

```
cat: file: Input/output error
```

`dmesg` reports messages like these:

```
[631847.884641] BTRFS warning (device loop0): csum failed ino 257 off 0 csum 1280268577 expected csum 2391276770
```

Having information that corruption occurs at `off 0`, so this is first 4096 bytes of file, indeed I'm able to retrieve non-corrupted blocks pretty easily:

```
dd if=file bs=4K skip=1
```

*Btw, writing and appending data to non-corrupted blocks of corrupted file also succeeds. At least when there is only one corrupted block and it's not the last. At first it surprised me, but then I think probably it's a good feature, so that applications that must append critical data won't stuck on a corrupted file.*

The question is how do I retrive data from corrupted block (or entire corrupted file)?

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: https://github.com/cblichmann/btrfscue

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort you can try

```
btrfs check --init-csum-tree /tmp/copy_of_the_device.bin
```

This command will change the filesystem and the result can be worse than before, so run this only on a dd or ddrescue copy of the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Kernel 5.11 introduced the option to mount and ignore file checksums. This will allow copying out data with bad csums.

```
mount -o rescue=ignoredatacsums /dev/sdX /mnt
```

This could let you completely recover a file if it is minimally damaged and you have some kind of parity, like [par2](https://infogalactic.com/info/Parchive)

Source: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-man5.html